# NHibernate: Create iCriteria without session

Tags: c#, session, nhibernate, icriteria

I want to construct *ICriteria's* and pass that on to a function. That function will open a session and transaction. Then the function executes the ICriteria.List(); and returns the list of objects, like the code below.

I want to do this because I only want to write `using(ISession Session = ...` and `Using(ITransaction Transaction = ...` once for collecting a list of objects. Otherwise I am repeating myself so many times.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Executes a ICriterion in a new session using a transaction.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of object to operate on.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="Criterion">The criterion to get the list of objects by.</param>
    /// <returns>The result of <c>(List<T>)Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(T)).Add(Criterion).List()</c></returns>
    public static List<T> CriterionToList<T>(ICriterion Criterion)
    {
        List<T> Objects = default(List<T>);
        using (ISession Session = SessionFactory.OpenSession())
        {
            using (ITransaction Transaction = Session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                Objects = (List<T>)Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(T)).Add(Criterion).List<T>();
                Transaction.Commit();
            }
        }
        return Objects;
    }
```

The only thing ICriteria.Add() accepts is a `ICriterion`.

**The Question**

`ICriterion` does not have a `.Add(..` So I **can't** do this:

```
ICriterion criterion = Restrictions.Eq(Property, Value).Add(...
```

How can I still achieve this, should I cast it to `ICriteria` first like so?

```
ICriterion criterion = ((ICriteria)Restrictions.Eq(Property, Value)).Add(...
```

*NOTE: The problem is that I am converting a huge project that uses DataTables to strong typed objects (compatible with NHibernate). So I have many, many compile errors that prevents me from testing my code without converting the whole project first.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can achieve this with [DetachedCriteria](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2008/10/05/querying-with-nhibernate.aspx). The syntax and usage would be like this:

```
var det = DetachedCriteria.For<T>.Add(Restrictions.Eq(prop, val));
using (var session = Config.OpenSession())
using (var txn = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    var result= det.GetExecutableCriteria(session).List();
}
```

You could easily encapsulate the transaction in a separate function:

```
public IList<T> GetList<T>(DetachedCriteria detachedCriteria)
{
    IList<T> result;
    using (var session = Config.OpenSession())
    using (var txn = session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        result = detachedCriteria.GetExecutableCriteria(session).List<T>();
        txn.Commit();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Ah yes! thats it! Its also stated in the reference: http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/ - "The DetachedCriteria class lets you create a query outside the scope of a session, and then later execute it using some arbitrary ISession." Its actually too easy, i should be ashamed asking this on SO! That I didn't notice `DetachedCriteria`. Thanks for the pointer.